# Orthogonal group is a subgroup of GL(V)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

How to show that Orthogonal group is a subgroup of the general linear group GL(V), where V is vector space?

Since general linear group GL(V) group of all linear transformation which are bijective i.e Invertible.

I know that an isometry is injective and also from the rank-nullity theorem that the image under the map from V to V has the dimension of the full group so it is surjective. But I need a more formal proof.

Also since to show it is subgroup we have show x*inverse of y belongs to Orthogonal group O(V) by using bilinear form isometry.
Please help me out to show it is surjective using bilinear forms and show it is subgroup.

Comment: Which definition of $O(V)$ do you use? Not $O(V)=\{\,\phi\in GL(V)\mid \forall x,y\in V\colon \langle \phi x,\phi y\rangle=\langle x, y\rangle\,\}$?

Comment: yes b(⟨ϕx,ϕy)=b(x,y) isometry of bilinear forms

Comment: Or dou you define $O(V)=\{\,\phi\in \operatorname{End}(V)\mid \forall x,y\in V\colon \langle \phi x,\phi y\rangle=\langle x, y\rangle\,\}$? In that case, you need to add the assumption that $\dim V<\infty$ to make it a group.

Comment: Can it be group for infinite dimensional case?

Comment: I want to show it for both finite as well as infinite dimensional case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi\in O(V)=\{\,\phi\in GL(V)\mid \forall x,y\in V\colon \langle \phi x,\phi y\rangle=\langle x, y\rangle\,\}$. Then in particular $\phi\in GL(V)$ and $\phi^{-1}$ exists.
Then for all $x,y\in V$, 
$$\langle \phi^{-1} x,\phi^{-1} y\rangle=\langle \phi\phi^{-1} x,\phi\phi^{-1} y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$$
and we conclude $\phi^{-1}\in O(V)$.
If also $\psi\in O(V)$, then for all $x,y\in V$, 
$$ \langle\psi\phi x,\psi\phi y\rangle =\langle \phi x,\phi y\rangle =\langle x,y\rangle$$
and we conclude $\psi\circ \phi\in O(V)$. Trivially, the identity is $\in O(V)$. So $O(V)$ is a non-empty subset of the group $GL(V)$ and closed under composition and taking inverses. We conclude that $O(V)$ is a subgroup of $GL(V)$.

Comment: how to assume that element in O(V) is element in GL(V)